# Team City Jenkins Pipeline Equivalent? Is it possible to import a script into another script?

Tags: kotlin, teamcity, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins-pipelines there is the concept of [*Shared Libraries*](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/),  where you can have parts of the pipeline extracted into another class to re-use in multiple other `Jenkinsfile`'s.

I am new to TeamCity and following this [post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2016/11/kotlin-configuration-scripts-an-introduction/) to set up a Configuration Script.

I have multiple repositories where the pipelines will be the same => eg. `Build, Test, Deploy`.  I do not want to create many scripts where they will be mostly identical apart from SCM URL.

Is it possible to inherit/import a script into another script in TeamCity to keep repetition to a minimum?

Comment: use template . .

Answer (score 2):

Possible since [TeamCity 2017.2](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Kotlin+DSL#KotlinDSL-AbilitytoUseExternalLibraries):

> Since TeamCity 2017.2 You can now use external libraries in your
>   Kotlin DSL code, which allows sharing code between different Kotlin
>   DSL-based projects. To use an external library in your Kotlin DSL
>   code, add a dependency on this library into the .teamcity/pom.xml file
>   in the settings repository and commit this change so that TeamCity
>   detects it. Then, before starting the generation process, the TeamCity
>   server will fetch the necessary dependencies from the Maven
>   repository, compile code with them, and then start  the settings
>   generator.

Comment: Keep in mind that there should be single repo with configuration. Teamcity doesn't support storage of configuration in each repo with code